# Python ignores setter

Tags: python, object, attributes, python-2.x, python-2.6

I am new to python and I try to create a class with get/set as property. I have copied a simple example from internet and it seems that Python ignores my setter. Am I doing something very stupid because I don't understand why it does not work.

I am running python 2.6.6 on Linux.

Thanks

```
#!/usr/bin/python

class Celsius:
    def __init__(self, temperature = 0):
        self._temperature = temperature

    def to_fahrenheit(self):
        return (self.temperature * 1.8) + 32

    @property
    def temperature(self):
        print("Getting value")
        return self._temperature

    @temperature.setter
    def temperature(self, value):
        if value < -273:
            raise ValueError("Temperature below -273 is not possible")
        print("Setting value")
        self._temperature = value

c = Celsius()

c.temperature = -5555

print c.temperature
```

The only thing I have in the command line is that it print -5555. It completely ignores my setter.

This is driving me crazy, any ideas?

Comment: Properties don't work with old-style classes. Inherit from `object` if you're not inheriting from anything else.

Comment: Is there a reason you need to use Python 2.6 in 2018? Python 2.7, I can understand, but  2.6 has been past EOL for something like 6 years, and I think the last distro LTS that maintained backward support for it expired earlier this year.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you've defined `Celsius` as an [old-style class](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#new-style-and-classic-classes).

The documentation for `property` makes this pretty clear:

> Return a property attribute for new-style classes (classes that derive from `object`).

The reason for this is that `@property` works by building a [descriptor](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/descriptor.html), and, as the docs on new-style classes say:

> The major motivation for introducing new-style classes is to provide a unified object model with a full meta-model. It also has a number of practical benefits, like the ability to subclass most built-in types, **or the introduction of “descriptors”, which enable computed properties.**

---

To fix this, just make `Celsius` a new-style class, by inheriting from `object`:

```
class Celsius(object):
    # all the rest of your code is the same.
```

---

Of course if you upgrade to Python 3, the problem goes away, because *all* classes are new-style classes. In particular, if you don't specify any other base classes, you get `object` as a base class,<sup>1</sup> so `class Spam:`, `class Spam():`, and `class Spam(object):` all mean the same thing in 3.x that `class Spam(object):` meant in 2.x.

---

<sub>1. This is actually two changes under the covers. First, the `class` statement always compiles to a call to a metaclass, never to the special old-style class construction. Second, the default metaclass, `type`, fills in `(object,)` if you pass it an empty list of bases. But you rarely need to understand any of this stuff, which is why it's in a footnote that hurts your eyes to squint at.</sub>

Comment: @user3483203 Yes. Let me update the answer to make that clearer.

Comment: Damn, i spent the afternoon and all I had to do was to add (object). Thanks!